# How does one find the corresponding SNPs in the pair of chromonosmes in a FASTA file?

Tags: bioinformatics, genomics

You might say I'm an amateur bioinformatician, or trying to become one.  I have a BAM file, from which I have succeeded, using [UGENE](http://ugene.net/) , in extracting consensus data in FASTA format.  I now see a single series of nucleotides, and their complements, for each chromosome.  What I don't see is two corresponding sequences.  SNP data (e.g., [SNPedia](http://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Rs17822931%28C;T%29) ) cites (if I understand it correctly) the SNP at the same site on each chromosome in the pair.  I don't know how to determine my variation, since I see only one nucleotide at any given site, not the pair.

Pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental here.  Thanks for any help navigating this jungle!

Comment: "Two corresponding sequences": corresponding to what? What SNP data? What SNP should be on both chromosomes? The link you gave seems to be for a SNP that can be either hetero- or homozygous. Why are you assuming it is homozygous in your data? What are your data? Please [edit] your question and clarify, it is very hard to understand what you're asking at the moment.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not expressing myself well... I'm kinda new to all this.  I am, in effect, talking about what I should expect to see in the case of a heterozygous SNP.  The question is simply this: If the particular genome I am examining happens to have a heterozygous SNP at some site, let's say (C;T), then how/where would I expect to see this in my data?  A consensus reflects the more prevalent read at that site, but, in this case, I would expect about 50% of the reads to be C, and 50% T... so the consensus isn't useful.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for simple one off queries it might be better to load the BAM file and a relevant reference genome into a browser like IGV and simply navigate to that specific position.

For some data I had lying around a heterozygous SNP would look like the picture below, there has been an A to G SNP and a C to T:

For longer lists of queries I would take a look at BEDtools: https://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/bedtools-suite.html

If this does not help you, I recommend you ask your question on https://www.biostars.org/ There you will find help from true bioinformaticians.

[image]

Comment: Right, so I've been looking at the BAM file, but I've yet to find any instance of a site where I see 50/50 reads of two nucleotides (e.g. 50% C and 50% T).  Is this what I should expect to find in the case of a heterozygous SNP genotype?  If so, then should I just ignore the consensus and just look at the BAM file?  I'd just like to validate that I am on the right track here...

Comment: I adjusted the answer to include a picture. Hopefully everything is more clear now

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't necessarily expect regions of heterozygosity to be apparent from a consensus fasta.  I'd eyeball if you know some potential sites, or run your .bam through something that will call SNPs.